# How to capture an unordered sequence of flags?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following examples:

```
FLAGS DCP
FLAGS PRE
FLAGS 4CH
FLAGS SCMS
FLAGS DCP PRE 4CH SCMS
FLAGS PRE 4CH DCP SCMS
FLAGS 4CH DCP PRE SCMS
```

And I would like to capture it like the following:

```
FLAGS DCP // group 1 = DCP
FLAGS PRE // group 1 = PRE
FLAGS 4CH // group 1 = 4CH
FLAGS SCMS // group 1 = SCMS
FLAGS DCP PRE 4CH SCMS // group 1 = DCP, group 2 = PRE, group 3 = 4CH, group 4 = SCMS
FLAGS PRE 4CH DCP SCMS // group 1 = PRE, group 2 = 4CH, group 3 = DCP, group 4 = SCMS
FLAGS 4CH DCP PRE SCMS // group 1 = 4CH, group 2 = DCP, group 3 = PRE, group 4 = SCMS
```

But using the following expression, it only captures the first flag after `FLAGS`:

```
^\s*FLAGS\s+((?:(?:DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)\s*?)+)
```

Is this possible with regex or should I just split what's after `FLAGS` then parse manually ?

Comment: Couldn't you just split on spaces?

Comment: You could use this pattern `^\s*FLAGS(?:\s+(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS))+\r?$` and get the captures [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*FLAGS%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%28DCP%7c4CH%7cPRE%7cSCMS%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=FLAGS+DCP%0d%0aFLAGS+PRE%0d%0aFLAGS+4CH%0d%0aFLAGS+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+DCP+PRE+4CH+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+PRE+4CH+DCP+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+4CH+DCP+PRE+SCMS&o=m)

Comment: @Amy Well, I'm asking if it's possible with regex, else that's what I'll do

Comment: a regex is not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I just need it for a single line and it'll be perfect !

Comment: What about: `^FLAGS\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?$`

Comment: @JvdV nice, haven't thought about that actually !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capturing group for the alternatives and repeat them inside a non capturing group prepended with 1+ whitespace chars.

In c# you could make use of the a repeating capturing group and get the [captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netframework-4.8)

```
^\s*FLAGS(?:\s+(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS))+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*FLAGS` Match 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char and match FLAGS
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)` Match 1+ whitespace chars and 1 of the alternatives
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `$`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*FLAGS%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%28DCP%7c4CH%7cPRE%7cSCMS%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=FLAGS+DCP%0d%0aFLAGS+PRE%0d%0aFLAGS+4CH%0d%0aFLAGS+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+DCP+PRE+4CH+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+PRE+4CH+DCP+SCMS%0d%0aFLAGS+4CH+DCP+PRE+SCMS&o=m)(Click on the Table tab:)

[image]

Comment: How neat! I know nothing about `c#` but I can see this is the organized method of doing this properly. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment. Maybe just create 4 capture groups repeating your sequence:

```
^\s*FLAGS\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?\s*(DCP|4CH|PRE|SCMS)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmPbat/3)